# Creating a Grouped Select in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js

It's relatively easy to create a select in Ember.js using [Ember.Select](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.Select&src=false).

The question is, how do I make this into a grouped select, using an optgroup. I don't think this is built in, but I'm guessing it's possible with some modifications to the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution that I came up with. https://gist.github.com/3297425

I had to make two collections. One grouped and the other just content so that the proper option can be selected.

```
groupedServiceCodes = [Ember.Object.create({label: 'Label for optgroup', content: Ember.A()}), …]
```

And then flatten the content from groupedServiceCodes down to maintain order for the select:

```
flattenedServiceCodes = [].concat(object.get('content'), …)
```

This is a bit of a hack, and I think Ember is wanting for a better solution, but this works for me. I would love to hear thoughts on improving this.

Answer (score 9):

This is natively supported by Ember now, but there are a few gotchas.  In 1.4.0, the following solution works...

Here's the example data:

```
foos: Ember.A([{value: 'foo', label: 'Foo', group: 'Foos'}, {value: 'bar', label: 'Bar', group: 'Bars'}, {value: 'bar2', label: 'Bar2', group: 'Bars'}, {value: 'foo2', label: 'Foo2', group: 'Foos'}])
```

Here's the view helper:

```
{{view Ember.Select content=controller.foos optionLabelPath='content.label' optionValuePath='content.value' optionGroupPath='group'}}
```

If, you just do the above you will get a select list that looks like this:

[image]

The only way I could get around this was to **sort the array first** by the grouped field:

```
foos: Ember.A([{value: 'foo', label: 'Foo', group: 'Foos'}, {value: 'bar', label: 'Bar', group: 'Bars'}, {value: 'bar2', label: 'Bar2', group: 'Bars'}, {value: 'foo2', label: 'Foo2', group: 'Foos'}]).sortBy("group")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any issue in GIT repo regarding this?

Answer (score 3):

The answers here are a bit outdated. Ember now supports grouping of stuff. Imagine you have:

```
App.SomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  content: [{value: 'foo', label: 'Foo', group: 'Foos'}, {value: 'bar', label: 'Bar', group: 'Bars'}]
})
```

You can then do

```
Ember.Select contentBinding='content' optionLabelPath='content.label' optionValuePath='content.value' optionGroupPath='group'
```

Notice that optionGroupPath does not do content.path, just path

Answer (score 1):

Ember.Select does not support optgroups, but you can extend Ember.Select to do so by providing a new template for it and a new template for options. I've done this to support chosen.js selects within Ember.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I'm trying to do that but debugging the context in handlebars is such a black box exercise. At this point I'm simply changing code at random to see what happens.

Comment: Debugging handlebars context is slightly easier now, using `{{log yourVar}}`, e.g. `{{log view}}`, which would do a `console.dir` to your browser's developer tools console.

Answer (score 0):

Ember now supports this out of the box. Refer to this git pull request https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2465